# How to limit country list for address form drop-down?

Tags: 8, users

In my store I defined list of supported billing and shipping countries at store settings. This list is respected during checkout process - limited list of countries is shown when customer is entering the address. But when user is on "Address book" tab of user profile page and wants to add new address list is not limited, but all countries are allowed there.

How can I limit list of displayed countries when editing address at address book user profile tab?

I tried using `hook_form_alter()` but I don't see country drop-down there?
Also tried `hook_preprocess_input()` and I see other fields, but not country drop-down.

`theme_preprocess_field()` didn't help either.

And of course, I didn't find that option in back-end.

Comment: That's really a bug, address book entry should respect those too. There is [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/3125801) about this.

Comment: I fount that patch my self and tried it, but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Found solution here:
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/customers/addresses/countries-and-subdivisions

Created new module "country_limit" added event subsriber like explained there:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\country_limit;

use Drupal\address\Event\AddressEvents;
use Drupal\address\Event\AvailableCountriesEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LimitCountriesEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[AddressEvents::AVAILABLE_COUNTRIES][] = ['onAvailableCountries'];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onAvailableCountries(AvailableCountriesEvent $event) {
    $countries = ['AT' => 'AT', 'DE' => 'DE', 'CH' => 'CH'];
    $event->setAvailableCountries($countries);
  }

}
```

and registered it like:

```
services:
  # Name of this service.
  my_config_events_subscriber:
    # Event subscriber class that will listen for the events.
    class: '\Drupal\country_limit\LimitCountriesEventSubscriber'
    # Tagged as an event_subscriber to register this subscriber with the event_dispatch service.
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

Event subsriber class is directly inside "src" dir, since I don't have other functionalities in this module.